# QtRPT : cannot find -lQtZint

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I have problem including QTRPT in my project.
I've copied all files and folders from "QtRptProject 1.5.2/QtRptProject" folder to my project folder (where .pro & .cpp & .h files are) and I've also inserted the line "include(QtRPT/QtRPT.pri)" in my .pro file (at the end).

The problem is that when compiling I get this error :
-1: error: cannot find -lQtZint

How can I fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a barcode feature, you need copy also zint-2.4.4 folder. Before building your project, you should build zint library first. Probably you problem in paths